AWS IAM Policy Simulator does not recognize explicit Deny in esource based Policy
I have got a Customer managed key in AWS KMS. The policy states an explicit Deny:
        {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/rudolfstarosta"
        },
        "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:eu-central-1:123456789012:key/c023a848-f330-4fa8-891c-858d461a6b71"
    }

When I try to simulate if the role is allowed to decrypt the key the IAM Policy Simulator claims "Allowed".
Why?
